When did the four Gospels receive their printed titles?
Bart Ehrman states that the four Gospels first started being called by their now known names sometime between 160-185 AD. But he also says that they didn't come with their titles printed until around 200 AD. Does he guess that based on the datings of certain titled manuscripts to around 200? Also, why would it have taken so long for the Gospels to get written titles after first being called by their modern names?

Great question! Where does Ehrman state this? Could be helpful to add some references to your Question.

@Stevecanhelp  see Bart Ehrman's blog post https://ehrmanblog.org/when-did-the-gospels-get-their-names/ He  dates the first time the gospels are known to be called by their names to about 185 ce when Irenaeus wrote Against Heresies.

Related Question: "Are there documents without titles?"https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/56974/are-there-any-ancient-manuscripts-of-books-without-titles

Ehrman , like other textual scholars, reaches that conclusion based on an analysis of the Apostolic Fathers and other early Church Fathers, several of whom refer to the gospels or quote from them but do not name them. He is particularly interested in Justin Martyr, who quotes rather extensively from the gospels that we call Matthew, Mark and Luke:

But the striking thing is that he does not call the Gospels by name.
He instead, regularly, calls them “Memoirs of the Apostles.”  And so
he does associate these books with apostles, but he never indicates
which apostles.  And he does not say that he thinks that the apostles
themselves wrote the books, only that these books preserve their
“memoirs” (meaning, their reminiscences of the life and teachings of
Jesus). 1

Ehrman goes on to state that:

Some thirty years after Justin, another proto-orthodox church father,
Irenaeus, does identify the Gospels by name. He is the first to do so.

Conclusion: Erhman and other textual scholars believe - with solid evidence - that no existing historical source refers to the gospels by name until Irenaeus c. 185 c.e. This does not prove with certainty that they did not have titles before this, but none of the Church Fathers refer to these titles. We have no actual copies of any gospel that goes back that far. As to the question of why it took so long for their titles to be included, that is beyond the scope of this site. However historians of the period often point to the increasing number of heretical gospels, which Irenaeus and other Church Fathers countered by developing the doctrine of apostolicity, one part of which is the idea that an authentic scripture must be written by either an apostle or a disciple of an apostle. Before this, there was little reason to associate each gospel with a particular author.

+1, good summary! re "As to the question of why it took so long for their titles to be included, that is beyond the scope of this site" - I'd actually disagree. I think that would be a perfect question for this site since it concerns the history and reception of a biblical text

Well, I went ahead and answered it so I can't disagree very vehemently.

Just because a person uses another designation for the gospels, instead of a scribal attribution superscript, does not mean that they didn’t have the superscripts at the time.
Justin may have preferred the designation "memoirs of the apostles" to indicate the trustworthy recollections of the apostles as found in the written record of the gospels.

In terms of site scope, we're generally comfortable on the majority of topics that academics in this space (such as Ehrman) would touch upon - the scope begins with text analysis, but extends to authorship, dating, critical theories, near-contemporary texts (apocrypha, apostolic fathers) and things like that, so long as they're scoped in a tight enough way to ensure they're answerable in the site format. So personally I would say that discussion (even speculation) around the history of texts and their names is appropriate.
